# Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/sandbox.ts' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable

Tags: typescript

I am getting this error on browser, my ts file is not working. can somebody help me in this?

can somebody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using the live server extension to run the code, if so, *.ts files won't be executed, because you have to covert then to javascript first, the browser understands only javascript

About MIME type, it is a convention for file extensions.
[here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial) is a nice tutorial on how compile typescript to javascript, hope it helps

Comment: still getting the same error. even i added the tsconfig.json file and yes i am using vs code live server

Comment: i have created the js file by running tsc.cmd file.ts. it created a js file for me but it is not executing in chrome.

Comment: can you able to share your code please